# El Capitan - Where to install application

Tags: macos, user-account

I'm developer and I'm providing my application with pkg installer. Before El Capitan, my installer was putting binaries to `/usr/bin`. With El Capitan I had to change it because of SIP, so now binaries go to `/usr/local/bin`. According to some reports `/usr/local/bin` is accessible only for sudoers, "regular" user can't access it. What should be the right location to install my application, so every user could access it?

Comment: If it was in /usr/bin before you needed admin rights i.e. use sudo before - regular accounts should not have been able to modify /usr/bin

Answer (score 3):

For command line tools accessed by any user, `/usr/local/bin` is the best location.

### System Wide Requires Admin

That `sudo` may also be required is also correct. An administrator should be required to make changes that affect other users of a computer. Ideally only users who are administrators can make system wide changes.

Practically this means your Installer package should **require admin rights** to be installed. Installer.app will take care of enforcement for you.

### pkgbuild

Hopefully you are using [`pkgbuild`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pkgutil.1.html) to create the Installer package.

If so, make sure you pass the destination path `/usr/local/bin` using the `--install-location` flag.

Avoid embedding standard parent folders in your package and installing to `/`. No package should need to install directly to `/`.

This will ensure any existing `/usr/local/bin` folder path retains its permissions and your package does not damage any existing settings. If the destination path does not exist, Installer.app will create it for you.